# Describes Equivalence Classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be the relation on the natural numbers defined by $(a,b)\in R$ if and only if $2\mid(a+b)$

I already proved this was an equivalence relation, but how do I determine the number of equivalence classes and describe them?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Play around with some values.  Can you find two integers that are not in the same equivalence class?  (Hint: start with simple integers.)  What are they?  Can you prove that they are in different equivalence classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just play around with some numbers. Consider $3 \in \mathbb N$. What is it related ("equivalent") to? Well $(3, 5) \in R$, since $2 \mid 8$. But $(3,6) \notin R$, since $2 \not\mid 9$. Continuing, we notice that:
$$
2 \mid (a + b) \iff a + b \text{ is even} \iff a \text{ and } b \text{ have the same parity}
$$
where by "parity", I mean whether a natural number is even or odd. So $R$ partitions $\mathbb N$ into two equivalence classes, namely:
\begin{align*}
[1]_R &= \{1, 3, 5, 7, \ldots\} \\
[2]_R &= \{2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots\}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**Take the number $1$ to be $a$, what kind numbers are related to $1$ in $R$? Then take $2$, and so on you will get the classes very fast.